# append array values to multiple divs in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to replace all titles from `.item` with the values from `array`. This is the array:

```
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
```

and the html:

```
<div class="item it1">
    <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
    <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
    <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
    <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

Tried with this but I gor script error and browser closed.

```
for (var i = itCats.length; i--;) {
    //arr[i] = '#' + arr[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(".item").length; i++) {
        $(".item p').html('itCats[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up a few tings. The easiest solution for your result is a `each` loop and use the `index` by the callback.

```
$('.item p').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(itCats[index]);
});
```

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

$('.item p').each(function(index) {
    $(this).text(itCats[index]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item it1">
    <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
    <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
    <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
    <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

You can even use a callback of `text` or `html`:

```
$('.item p').text(function(index) {
    return itCats[index];
});
```

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

$('.item p').text(function(index) {
    return itCats[index];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item it1">
    <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
    <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
    <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
    <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

Or to show another solution, as arrow function:

```
$('.item p').text(i => itCats[i]);
```

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
$('.item p').text(i => itCats[i]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item it1">
    <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
    <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
    <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
    <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of errors is here:

`$(".item p').html('itCats[i]);`

You've messed with quotes, it should be as follows:

`$('.item p').html(itCats[i]);`.

Comment: There are more errors and so this is not an answer.

Comment: indeed, there are more errors but script is not good too. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Various errors in your code

1. Selector string starts with `"` and ends with `'` make it correct as `".item p"` or `'.item p'`
2. The `$(".item p")` selects all elements use **[`eq(i)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq)** to get specific one using index.
3. The nested loop is not necessary here.
4. Remove the unnecessary `'` inside **[`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html)** method.

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

for (var i = itCats.length; i--;) {
  $(".item p").eq(i).html(itCats[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item it1">
  <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
  <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
  <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
  <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

---

You can make it simpler with **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** with a callback which internally iterates over the elements.

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

$('div.item p').html(function(i) {
  return itCats[i];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item it1">
  <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
  <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
  <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
  <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this will remove `p` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one `each()` loop

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

$('.item').each(function(i) {
  $(this).find('p').text(itCats[i])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item it1">
  <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
  <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
  <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
  <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.text()` callback function to access elements index and return required value from array to set as new text:

```
$('.item p').text(function(i){
  return itCats[i];
})
```

```js
var itCats = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
$('.item p').text(function(i){
  return itCats[i];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item it1">
    <p>title 1</p>
</div>
<div class="item it2">
    <p>title 2</p>
</div>
<div class="item it3">
    <p>title 3</p>
</div>
<div class="item it4">
    <p>title 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend to remove `o` from parameters because it is unnecessary here.

Answer (score -2):

You may have some typo about single quote & double quote in the line `$(".item p').html('itCats[i]);`

You could take advantage from jQuery `.each(function(index))` to also get the element index

Try this example: https://jsfiddle.net/157xr3p9/